# How to select iframe by width or height in python 2.7 selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I try to select this iframe:

```
<iframe width="318" style="border: 0px none; padding: 0px;" height="158"></iframe>
```

As you can see, it has no name. I know I could do it with:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(5)
```

Problem is that the page changes, so this iframe is not always (5) on page, so I need different way how to select it. Is there a way how to select iframe by its width or height?

Answer (score 1):

You can locate it by `height` attribute as

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@height="158"]'))
```

or both by `height` and `width`:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@height="158" and @width="318"]'))
```

but you'd better to locate it as a descendant of some ancestor `div`, e.g.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="some_id"]//iframe'))
```

as it seem to be more reliable way